# Excel VBA - Name.RefersTo formula proper address specification

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have a formula in the cell, let's call it Source Cell, which is linked to other cells in the sheet. 
My goal is to create the named range which would have this formula saved as a RefersTo property of that name.

When I add new name like this

`wbk.Names.Add Name:=NameTitle, RefersTo:=Cell.Formula`

the new name refers to the source cell as A1 and therefore all linked cells are offset by the number of rows and columns of source cell

I thought a while and tried RefersToLocal - didn't help. Than I tried ReferstoR1C1 - that helped, but only if I select one cell. When I select the range of several cells and loop through each cell - it still creates names with a formula from the first cell.

I understand it's due to the way ranges and address are specified but am I doing something wrong and how to fix it? Any ideas? File attached.

My code

```
Sub TestNameCreation()
Dim Cell As Range, CellFormula As String, strName As String, nme As Name
Dim rng As Range, msg As String

Set rng = Range(ActiveWindow.Selection.Address)
For Each Cell In rng.Cells

    CellFormula = Cell.FormulaR1C1
    strName = "Test" & Format(Now(), "hhmmss")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=strName, RefersToR1C1:=CellFormula
    Set nme = Names(strName)
    msg = msg & "Cell: " & Cell.Address & vbCrLf & "Name: " & _
        nme.Name & vbCrLf & "RefsTo: " & nme.RefersTo & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Next Cell

MsgBox msg
```

End Sub`

[image]

Comment: Could you give an example of what you expected to see? When i run it i get for example R4C2 in cell "A1" with the formula =CELL("address",B4)

Comment: You can use Cell.Text if you want R1C1 that changes i.e.  CellFormula = Cell.Text

Comment: HI mate.Thanks for your reply, I tried Cell.Text - it gives the value of the cell, not the formula, which is not what I am after. However, coming back to this this morning with fresh head I think the issue is that when the formula is analyzed and stored in memory - all the relative links are offset if not the anchor cell is selected. Will give it a try. Haven't tried your other approach yet

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around. All the created names are correct. The thing with Named Ranges is that if some cell in the RefsTo formula is not absolute, then it's shown according to the selected cell. So no wonder I had an impression that the formula is wrong.